# How to change the <base href="10.10.10.10/myfoldername" /> in joomla

Tags: joomla

How to change the:

```
<base href="10.10.10.10/myfoldername" />
```

in joomla. I want it to be like the relative path instead of actual path.
Would it be possible. Please Help

Comment: The base path is probably invalid. Missing protocol ( `http://` or `https://` )

Answer (score 0):

You can change or remove the Base URL in Joomla by adding the following codes in your theme:

```
// remove the Base URL
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
unset($doc->base);

// edit the Base URL
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->base = 'Any valid path or URL';
```

It's suggested to remove it to avoid path errors in some cases, especially in mixed HTTP-HTTPS environment.

Comment: Where to change.. In which file I should change. Any step by step guide you can give me?

Comment: Add it in your **template**'s `index.php`. Also, check out the Configuration file : `configuration.php` , the `live_site` variable.